# Machine learning functions to deal with a large amount of data, by distributing work across multiple cores

Tags: r, optimization, tree, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to run some machine learning algorithms using r on some large data (not big data).

The (relatively small) toy data I am using to test my code has just under 100'000 rows, and 850 columns (including 1 factor column with 14 levels)

I am trying to run an svm (package: `e1071`), a tree (package: `tree`), a random forest (package: `randomForest`) and a boosted tree (package: `gbm`).

The computer I am using has 12 cores. When I open the activity monitor the functions seems to use the cores randomly (maximum 4 at a time). **Is there a function where the work is distributed more efficiently across all cores?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `caret` package can do all of those while allowing you to use multicore options.

```
library(doMC) 
registerDoMC(cores = 5)
#All subsequent models are then run in parallel 
model <- train(y ~ ., data = training, method = "rf")
```

That is an example from http://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel.html